# Is the close voting system lacking or a hassle?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Lately, more and more questions that are off-topic have garnered close votes with the 'tech support' reason, even when they obviously aren't. Examples [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/58303/19174) and [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/58276/19174).

We have seen a definite increase in close votes, and I understand that they can be a hassle to vote on. I suspect that the reason that 'tech support' gets chosen for off-topic votes is because it's the default off-topic reason.

On to my question: **Is it too hard or too much work to select a proper close reason?** This is *not* a sarcastic question, I'm genuinely interested in whether voting to close is too time-intensive.

Choosing a proper close reason is important. Firstly, for site stats and seeing whether a certain close reason pops up (too) often. Secondly – and more importantly – for the asker. If a question is off-topic here, but would be useful and on-topic on another Stack, we’d like to know. That way, the question can be migrated and get an answer, helping out another Stack in the process. Moreover, seeing your question closed with a reason that does obviously not apply or you cannot make any sense of is far from welcoming to new users.

If we can do anything to make close voting easier or faster, I'm in for trying to arrange that. But in the meantime, I'd prefer people handling less close votes but do them well than empty their review queue and be shoddy.

Comment: We need a "this in not within the scope of the site" close reason.

Comment: I'll be honest — I've just stopped reviewing questions. When there's a queue of 25 to 45 *every day*, I can't face it. I tried proposing the Graphic Design Software Support stack on Area 51, but in four months there have been 18 followers and nobody else has suggested a potential question, so clearly the idea isn't popular.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum That's quite the pity. I can imagine those numbers looming intimidatingly, but please consider *not doing all of them*. If you can just review a couple, but be thorough and concise about it, then don't hesitate to leave the rest. There's exactly 40 users with close vote privileges at the moment, so you really don't have to review every nominee.

Comment: Personally I think the CV situation here on GD is fine. IMO all we need are more active members but that's not something we can have too much effect on